# Nginx Reverse Proxy not redirecting?

Tags: networking, proxy, nginx

### Update

I think it narrows down to this:

For some reason the host name matters to Nginx when it's trying to figure out whether to proxy the request.  If the host name is set to `git.example.com` the request does not seem to go through, but if it's set to `203.0.113.2` then it goes through.  Why does the host name matter?

[Filed an issue with Nginx here](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/281)

### Original Question

When I type in the IP address of the reverse proxy directly into my browser bar, it does perform the redirect.

In this case I'll enter `203.0.113.2` and the redirect to `203.0.113.1` is performed.

When using a URL that is resolved via the `/etc/hosts` entry `203.0.113.2 git.example.com` the "Welcome to Ngnix page" is shown instead of the page that would result from the redirect.

IIUC the browser will first resolve the IP address `203.0.113.2` per the URL entry `git.example.com`, and so both should result in the proxy configuration being invoked, but that is not what happens.

This is the configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name git.example.com;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; # pass on real client IP

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://203.0.113.1:3000;
    }
}
```

One interesting thing is that I can navigate to for example:

```
http://203.0.113.2/issues
```

If I then change `203.0.113.2` with `git.example.com` I get Nginxs "404 not found" page.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a few hours yesterday fiddling with nginx and gogs configurations with no luck.

What did work was to set the A Record on the DNS configuration of the domain name for the `git` subdomain to point to the right IP address.

Comment: I I actually have this working when I run all the containers separately outside of docker-compose.  I'm going to try going back to the manual setup again and see if it still works or if nginx has changed something that now makes it not work.  I'll post all my steps in detail so that I can show if docker-compose is causing it.